# Saving variables within while loop

Tags: javascript, php, variables, while-loop

not pretty sure how you do this. But I want to save my javascript variables as data(1,2,3,4,...) in my while loop. Happy for any help! Thanks

```
$id = 0;
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($data)){

$id = $id + 1;
$data = $rows['data'];

?>


<script>
    var id = '<?php echo $id; ?>'; //1,2,3,4,5,6,...

    var data = '<?php echo $id; ?>'; // Example - Data 1 = Frog, Data 2 = Bird 

    // So here I want to sava variables so the name will be
    // var "data+'id'"; 
    // And the output is data for that row 
</script>


<?php
}
?>

//And here outside I want to use the variables like this:
document.write(data1); writes out "Frog"
document.write(data2); writes out "Pig"
```

Comment: If your IDs are increasing numbers, why don't you want to use an Array in your JS?

Comment: why do you loop multiple `<script>`-tags anyway? With code like this you always override your data

Comment: I'm not really good at this... I'm getting new data from my array in mysql and need to save it down so smart as possible. Dont want to save each row for itself outside while loop @sebastian_oe

Comment: Make an array with key value pairs like Data1:pig, Data2:bird

stringify it using JSON.encode in PHP and send it across to the javascript and later access it using after doing json.parse and enjoy.

Comment: Why dont you make `data` an array in JS?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
var jsData = [];

<?php
$id = 0;
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
    $data = $rows['data'];
?>
    jsData[<?php echo $id; ?>] = '<?php echo $data; ?>';

<?php
    $id++;
}
?>

</script>
```

This would yield a JS Array called jsData where your ID is the index and which is filled with the PHP `$data` values.

Answer (score 0):

Declare `$data = new Array();` just before the WHILE LOOP then in the WHILE LOOP you could do `$data['id'][$id]= $id` which will collect all the IDS.

Add `$data['data'][$id]= $row['data']` below it so as also to collect each `data` that you want.

in the script tag do this:

`var id = <?php echo '['.join(',', $data['id']).']' ?> //will create --> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`
`var data = <?php echo '['.join(',', $data['data']).']' ?> //--> ['cat', 'dog', 'cow', 'sheep']`

now you can access the variable in the Javascript array created eg. `$data[0] // 'cat'`